# How can I remove the subfolder form URL after .htaccess redirects to new URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a website which detects the user-agent and if it is a mobile device then  redirects the link

```
domain.co.nz
```

to

```
m.domain.co.nz
```

(the redirect rules have been written in the .htaccess of the root directory) given below:

```
## Mod_rewrite in use.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.domain.co.nz/m [R=301,L]
```

This rewrite works good, but what I want to achieve is that after getting redirected to new URL, I want to strip out "/m" from http://m.domain.co.nz/m 
once It has got redirected

I have tried this rewrite rule given below but it just doesn't removes the  "/m" from redirected URL

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.domain\.co\.nz$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/
RewriteRule (.*) /m/$1
```

Spent hours on different solutions but nothing is working out.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache, and change the first `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.domain.co.nz/ [R=301,L]
```

Without `/m`